# Writing multi-page applications using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I can't seem to find an example online that gives me a working multi-page application written using angular that also makes use of ui-router. I understand how it is possible to have various templates and interchange them when necessary (i.e. http://plnkr.co/edit/TahGIArycr2eHayoOpEA?p=preview). However, these templates share the same `<head>` etc... I would like to see an example where the entire page is different, including the `<head>`. Any pointers?

Comment: Why do you want to use angularjs ui-router for MPA? If MPA you can use server side script for routing instead and easier.

Comment: Because I want to be able to make use of browser-side stuff like localStorage. For instance, I have a situation where the page design is completely different, but it is part of the same application and so share the localStorage. Using server-side routing will not allow me to utilise stuff like that.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase that. I am not restricted by necessarily having to use ur-router. I just want to be able to have various multiple pages, but part of the same angular app.